# Accessing private variable from static function in php

Tags: php, static

I've got a private variable in my class

```
private $noms = array(
        "HANNY",
        "SYS",
        "NALINE"
);
```

I want to access it from a static method:

```
public static function howManyNom($searchValue){

        $ar = $this->noms;

        foreach($ar as $key => $value) {

...
```

But as normal I cant retrieve it with $this because there's no instance on a static method.

What's the right syntax to get $noms inside my static function?

Comment: make the $noms array static also

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Make this attribute static too!

```
private static $noms = array(
    "HANNY",
    "SYS",
    "NALINE"
);


public static function howManyNom($searchValue){

    $ar = self::$noms;

    foreach($ar as $key => $value) {
```

Comment: already tried and when I call it by  self::noms it says 'nom' is undefined

Comment: Nice shot ;) I hopped there was a solution to keep it not static (it is cleaner) but that's enough :) thanks

Comment: I think, I your case it's the cleanest way you can reach :)

Comment: Solved my problem! :)

Answer (score 3):

To access the $noms array make it static, you do that like so:

`private static $noms = array();`

You then access that like so:

`self::$noms['some key']`;

Answer (score 1):

You have to make the noms static, too and access it via self::$noms.