# Access global $var in class and methods / functions

Tags: php, function, class, variables, scope

Rather novice when it comes to php - so looking for some help.

I have a fairly basic php based site where I include a utility class which contains lots of useful functions to help out throughout the site.

```
 class utility {

    // Get current scheme
    public static function get_scheme() {

        $scheme = 'http://';

        if ((!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] !== 'off') || $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443) {
```

I call these functions throughout the site by using for example `utility::get_scheme();`.

I store variables to reuse throughout in two main arrays `$vars` and `$meta`.

My problem lies when I have specific functions within the utility class whereby I want to access something from either the `$vars` and/or `$meta` variables within a function. How would you access my global variables from within a class function?

```
public static function debug() {

    global $vars;

    foreach ($vars as $var) {
```

I have read up about the use of `global` not being the right way to go about things. And I am wondering whether it would easier **not** to store all the functions wrapped in a class.

Comment: You mean `global  $vars` is not working?

Comment: It is, but as I mentioned, reading other threads, this doesn't seem the best way to approach.

Comment: Global variables usually become an issue during debugging. It becomes tricky to detect which class or a piece of code edits it's value and due to this, they are usually bad. However, if these don't change and if they are used just to get values, I suppose you can declare them as global constants.

Comment: Global variables also don't guarantee what values they would be usually having when you are using it for some computation or for printing something on the screen, unless you have a very good execution workflow management.

Comment: You can make `$var` and `$meta` static variables - https://stackoverflow.com/a/11901220/296555. Does that work for your use case?

Comment: @waterloomatt Do you mean like this:

`<?php
    
  class utility {
  
    private static $settings;
    
    public static function get_value() {
      
      return self::$settings;
    }
  }
?>`

Comment: @waterloomatt But when I call `utility::get_value();` nothing is returned

Comment: That's right. You need to define some values first. `$settings` is NULL until you put something in it. You have a few options for manipulating `$settings`. Ex. http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/db265b727c0bbcae730e76e05c50f46becf3a23b

Comment: I already have the $settings variable outside the scope of the class, I am trying to bring that variable into the scope of the class and it's methods/functions

Comment: Same concept - http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2169bd0b19e18875ab25215254f96e1cf5e07858